# Getting all letters between two specified letters

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

For objective-c, how do I find out the letters between two given letters. For example, for two letters A and D, I should get A, B, C, D.

Comment: you can get it from ASCII value.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, I had no starting point to have "tried" anything with. I tried searching on the internet and viewed NSString documentation to find some relevant information which I was unable to get. I don't see any logic behind putting all that non-relevant information up and make the whole sense of the question ambiguous.

Comment: int start = 'A';
 int end = 'D';
 for (int c = start; c <= end; c++)
 {
  NSLog(@"%c",c);
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this code:

```
NSString *start = @"A";
NSString *end = @"D";
unichar startChar = [start characterAtIndex:0];
unichar endChar = [end characterAtIndex:0];
for (unichar c = startChar; c <= endChar; c++)
{
    NSLog(@"%c",c);
}
```

result:

```
2012-12-17 19:01:36.259 Test[7492:907] A
2012-12-17 19:01:36.263 Test[7492:907] B
2012-12-17 19:01:36.264 Test[7492:907] C
2012-12-17 19:01:36.265 Test[7492:907] D
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest code would be:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'd'; c++)
    NSLog(@"char = %c", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**

```
unichar StartChar = [@"R" characterAtIndex:0];
unichar EndChar = [@"X" characterAtIndex:0];
for (unichar Result = StartChar; c <= EndChar; c++)
{
    NSLog(@"%c",Result);
}
```

**Second**

```
NSString *string = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int startIndex = [string rangeOfString:@"A"].location;
NSString *subString = [string substringFromIndex:startIndex];

int EndIndex = [subString rangeOfString:@"H"].location;

NSString*result = [subString substringToIndex:EndIndex+1];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

**Third**

```
NSArray *string = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles];
int startIndex = [string indexOfObject:@"D"];
int EndIndexIndex = [string indexOfObject:@"I"];

for (int i=startIndex; i<=EndIndexIndex; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[string objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```